# Disabling ligatures only for small caps style?

Tags: small-caps, microtype, ligatures

I want to write the word Beruflich in small caps using the \scshape command. However, when the letters fl are next to each other they are output without small caps. When they are separated by a space it works as intended but of course I don't want the space (see image below).

[image]

A minimal code example is given here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

\begin{document}
\scshape{Beruflich Beruf lich}
\end{document}
```

The only solution I have found so far is disabling ligatures the following way.

```
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = *, family = *}
```

But I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to disable ligatures everywhere. Can I just disable them for small caps? I have tried:

```
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = *, family = sc*}
```

but it does not work unfortunately.

Comment: A workaround: `\textsc{Beruf{}lich}`.

Comment: scshape is not a family, but a shape so you need `\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = *, shape = sc*}`.

Comment: while @UlrikeFischer of course gave the correct answer, this certainly looks like a bug in sourcesanspro (it works for me with TL'19, but not with TL'20 or 21)

Comment: @Robert yes, I quite agree it looks like a bug.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  I've reported it [here](https://github.com/silkeh/latex-sourcesanspro/issues/8)