# How to fix ligatures with Source Sans Pro font and small caps?

Tags: ligatures, sourcesanspro

The Source Sans Pro font (provided by `sourcesanspro` package) does not appear to provide ligatures for `fi` and `fl`.

The following document shows the problem with small caps (and `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sourcesanspro}
\begin{document}
\textsf{effect efficient filled flip : \textsc{effect efficient filled flip}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to fix this problem (and fix this [issue](https://github.com/silkeh/latex-sourcesanspro/issues/8))?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598489/47927

Comment: @JasperHabicht I'm looking for a solution that works automatically (which could be used as a patch to the sourcesanspro.sty file).

Answer (score 1):

(Probably should be a comment, but as I need to attach an image …)

I am not getting that at all, with both `pdflatex` and `LuaLaTeX`: Instead I get proper small caps (without ligatures, as expected). I am using TexLive 2021 on Windows 10, if that matters.

That said, have you tried to “break up” the ligatures, at it were?

`effect e{f}{f}icient or f\kern0pt{}illed or f{}lip`

[image]

PS: Seeing as how (according to the bug tracker) it seems to affect only Type1 fonts, it might be a caching issue or something as I normally use LuaTeX throughout.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround... but I'm looking for a solution that works automatically.

Comment: Right. I thought this was a one-time issue, so I offered a stop-gap solution. Switching away from pure `pdflatex` certainly seems to do the trick, though, if that is an option for you. It worked for me out of the box with `LuaLaTeX`.